# Gambler's ruin probabilities for fair games with multiple initial capital values in R

Tags: r, probability

Consider a gambler walks into a casino with  dollars in his pocket, intending to play  fair games where he may lose or win one dollar each time. Since the casino will only let him play when he has at least one dollar to put at stake, there is a certain probability that he will go bankrupt before the intended  games have been played.

How could I simulate and graph the ruin probabilities with all initial capital values ranging from 1 to 10 dollar in R? Thanks in advance.

Reference code:

```
# gambler_ruin(k, n, p)
  #   k: Gambler's initial stake
  #   n: Gambler plays until either $n or Ruin
  #   p: Probability of winning $1 at each play
  #   Function returns 1 if gambler is eventually ruined
  #                    returns 0 if gambler eventually wins $n

gambler_ruin <- function(k, n, p) {
    stake <- k
    while (stake > 0 & stake < n) {
        bet <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(1-p, p))
        stake <- stake + bet
    }
    if (stake == 0) return(1) else return(0)
    }   

k <- 10 
n <-  40  
p <- 1/2  
trials <- 1000
simlist <- replicate(trials, gamble(k, n, p))
mean(simlist) # Estimate of probability that gambler is ruined

# For p = 0.5, exact probability is (n-k)/n 
if(p == 0.5) {
    (n-k)/n
}

# Gambler's ruin
set.seed(2020)
final<-c()
par(mfrow=c(3, 3))

for (i in 1:9) {
start <- 20
gain <- start
vec <- c(start)
i <- 0
while (0 < gain &&  gain < 60)
{ i <- i + 1
gain <- gain + sample(c(-1, 1), 1)
if (i == 200) twty <- gain
vec <- c(vec, gain)
}

time <- i
if (gain == 60) yes <- 1 else yes <- 0

  plot(0:i,vec,type="l",xlab="", ylab="Total Gain",yaxt="n", ylim=c(-5, 65),
      xlim= c(0, 1000))
  axis(2, at=c(0, 20, 40, 60))
# abline(v = 200,lty=2)
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
abline(h = 60, lty = 2)
final <- c(final, i)
}
```

Comment: You are interested in simulation rather than calculation?

Comment: Yes, simulate and graph if possible. I also added reference code. Thank you.

Comment: So you seem to have run and graphed nine simulations with $N=20$ and $M=1000$.  See https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWx44.png What are you asking us?  Do you want to run many more simulations at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean the code above is the corresponding code of the question?

Comment: Apart from the value of $N$ ($20$ is not "all initial capital values ranging from 1 to 10 dollar") and the fact you have individual runs rather than probabilities, it looks sensible though I have not checked your code

Comment: Any ideas how to modify the code?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.